# Android: 7zip a folder using Apache Commons Compress

Tags: android, apache, 7zip

I have included the following in my `.gradle`: 
`compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8'`

I want to 7zip a **folder**. I have tried

```
SevenZOutputFile sevenZOutput = new SevenZOutputFile(file);
SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZOutput.createArchiveEntry(fileToArchive, name);
sevenZOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);
sevenZOutput.write(contentOfEntry); //this is what I don't understand!!
sevenZOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
```

I require some help and assistance in accomplishing the above task.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going with `.zip` for now. Please update me if you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I heard that apache zip does not supported compression/extraction on password protected files, how are you handling that then?

Answer (score 1):

```
sevenZOutput.write(contentOfEntry);
```

replace to

```
sevenZOutput.write(Files.toByteArray(fileToArchive));
```

Comment: I heard that apache zip/7zip does not supported compression/extraction on password protected files, how are you handling that then?