# Why can't I decompress this LZW file in Java on Android?

Tags: java, android, compression

I need to decompress a text file I download from the internet, around 256 kB compressed and 2 mB when extracted. The Linux `file` utility tells me it's "compress'd data 16 bits". Looking into it, I have discovered that `compress` uses the LZW algorithm. 7-zip says the "type" of the file is "Z" (so is its extension), and is able to decompress the file without any issues, so the problem isn't in the file. I also know that the problem isn't in how I'm downloading the file, since the stream of compressed bytes matches the bytes shown when opening hex editor.

The file itself is a plain-text Nowcasting matrix file from Environment Canada. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add another link.

I have been unable to find any built-in LZW decoders, so I've had to resort to using third-party libraries. There are quite a few of these, but none of the ones I have tried so far have been able to decompress the file.

lzwj - throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 40223, size is 256`. (The index itself isn't really important). However, the default codeword length is 12. I have changed the source to have a codeword length of 16, as the output of `file` seems to indicate (am I wrong in this assumption?), but it throws the same exception (the index shown in the error is for the codeword length of 16).

[This algorithm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lzwcomp/) also throws an index out-of-bounds exception, after a few modifications to take an input stream instead of a file. However, as it appears to have been written by a student for an assignment, I'm not comfortable using it anyway.

[This library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15160/LZW-Compression-Algorithm-Implemented-in-Java) unfortunately only has a `compress` method, and does not do decompression.

7-zip JBinding seemed like my best bet, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on Android, neither with the all-platforms jar or the ARM-only jar.

I have come across a couple more libraries and individual class source files, but they have no license associated with them and I'm avoiding copyrighted code.

Can anyone help me find out the cause of any of these errors, or provide an alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried Apache Commons Compress: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282358/android-7zip-a-folder-using-apache-commons-compress

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I don't know how that flew under my radar, I didn't even see any other LZW-related questions on here mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract and use the [`unlzw()` routine in pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz/blob/master/pigz.c#L3205).